# How do I use F#'s "with" assignment keywords with list properties in records?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to learn the basics of F#, and stumbled over the "with" keyword which seems to be an extremely elegant way of returning new instances as slightly modified copies of the original object (or record). I might have misunderstood, though, or I'm getting my syntax wrong.

The compilation errors I get for the snippet below are

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    string    but here has type    string list
>   and
>   error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    string list    but here has type    string

```
let nokids = { Name = "alex something"; Age = 23; Kids = [] }
printfn "%A" nokids

let married = { nokids with Name = "alex newname" };
printfn "%A" married

let withkids = { married with Kids = married.Kids :: "john"}
```

Why would that not create a new record instance with a "Kids" list containing "john"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "with" syntax is fine, your list construction syntax is not ;)

```
let withkids = { married with Kids = "john" :: married.Kids }
```

Left side is the new element, right side is the rest of the list. Using `::` you can only append elements from the head side (which is the usual pattern with [cons lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons), as F# lists are an example of those).

Comment: Oh my, the blindlingly obvious staring me in the face. Thank you!